# Multi-string data-set without z layer, applying ordinal values as a workaround

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, vector

I'm new to GIS and have been learning a lot over the last few weeks, however, I've finally come to a point where I could use some help.

I'm working with the pdx_streets data-set from http://www.civicapps.com, which doesn't include a z-layer or elevation relating to the rendering order for ramps, overpasses, tunnels, bridges, etc.

This data-set does include F and T ordinal values(-2 to 5), which can be applied as a work-around; but what is the best way to apply this?

Currently, I have all of the street styles entered, one solution would be list each value and apply using the render order, however, this would create a lot of duplication for each style.

QGIS 2.10

Metadata: http://www.portlandmaps.com/metadata/index.cfm?&action=DisplayLayer&LayerID=52058

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the problem correctly, you can use symbol levels to achieve this.

I'm attaching a simple example where I want to colour points based on an integer attribute. By selecting symbol levels, the points are styled according to the value *and* the order of drawing also depends on the same value. The smaller the number the "lower" it appears in the rendered image:

[image]

You can use a similar approach to draw road segements in their z-order. You could use either the F or T attribute or take the average of the two and create a new pseudo-z attribute for styling.

Comment: Thanks a bunch -- Your approach worked with a few tweaks. Moving to rule-based and combing the road styles, F and T attributes, then moving the road borders from the road styles to the F and T attributes, then adjusting the render order for each.